# Target Exec command not found - ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio for macOS

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, .net-core, csproj, visual-studio-mac

In .NET core .csproj file there is following target:

```
<Target Name="PreBuild" AfterTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="dotnet bundle clean" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet bundle" />
</Target>
```

I would have thought this should successfully run the commands as those commands are correct for .NET core CLI on macOS.

However it causes following build error:

```
Target PreBuild:
    dotnet bundle clean
    No executable found matching command "dotnet-bundle"
```

Why is it trying to execute 'dotnet-bundle' and not 'dotnet bundle'?

The project was originally developed on Windows and I only ran into this problem after trying to get it up and running on macOS. But as far as I know, it should be possible.

`dotnet --info` output on macOS:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.500
 Commit:    b68b931422

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.14
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.14-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.500/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.6
  Commit:  3f4f8eebd8

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.1.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.1.500 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: .NET has this logic for falling back for commands. If there's no built-in `dotnet foo` command, it falls back to calling `dotnet-foo`. There's no standard `dotnet bundle` command, so it's trying to find `dotnet-bundle`. Where is this command coming from? Is there a `DotNetCliToolReference` in the project file? What does it look like? What version of .NET Core is this?

Comment: It is .NET Core 2.1 and there is the following in project file: `<DotNetCliToolReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.8.391" />`

Comment: My fault for asking a question with an ambiguous answer. What does `dotnet --info` say on Windows vs macOS?

Comment: I don't have access to my Windows machine right now, hence trying to get it working on macOS. But I added the output of the command from macOS above.

Comment: This is a bug in Visual Studio for Mac. First it does not restore dotnet cli tool references. However even if you restore them from the command line using `dotnet restore` or `msbuild /t:restore` then msbuild still fails to find dotnet bundle, even though `dotnet bundle` will work from the command line after running the restore from the command line.

Comment: @MattWard what's the status of fixing that? i've tried various methods to hack around it and i can't find any magic sauce

Comment: The restoring of dotnet cli tool references is fixed but running `dotnet bundle` as part of the build is not working the last time I checked this.